# Where can I find the fitting kit number on a Thule roof rack mount?

Tags: parts

I am looking for a Thule roof rack on second-hand online market places. As a roof rack has specific fitting kits that clamp on the roof of a specific car model I am looking for a way to determine the kit type that a seller is offering.

Thule uses numbers to identify different kits. I know what number I need, but I am looking for a way to derive the fitting kit number from the physical part itself, when no box or receipt is present and when the seller has no idea.

From the pictures online, all fitting kits look more or less the same to me, so I find it hard to distinguish them visually by shape or features.

Is the kit number printed/stamped/etched on the physical kit itself? If so, where?

Comment: Perhaps the Thule web site or a Thule dealer?

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear, but it's about identifying an existing physical fitting kit, which is not in my possession. While the Thule website has an [elaborate part catalogue](https://www.thule.com/en-us/thule-support/spare-parts) it does not describe how one should identify a part. As the part is not yet in my possession I cannot take it with me to the Thule dealer such that they can identify it. I was hoping someone would know *how* one can identify the part such that I could do that myself.

Comment: I think what @jwh20 might be suggesting is why don't you ask this question through the Thule web site. Whether their site is intuitive, they should be more than ready to give you the information you need. They *want to sell parts* so it only makes sense to support a potential customer. I'll bet if you look on their website, they'll have a means by which you can post or send an inquiry on the subject. They, bar far, are going to know more about it than we would.

Comment: I see. I've sent them an e-mail. If I get a useful reply I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

According to Thule customer service the pad and the metal clamp of the fitting kit have a number stamped on them as shown in below pictures:

[image: Fitting stamped 469]

[image: Fitting stamped 328]